# How to select some selected Pivot table area?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select and copy some selected area of a pivot table. I am able to determine the amount of area I want and am able to display the range in a message box which is not my objective. I want to copy that selected range. My code looks like this.
I want to copy the Values in the range (toprow1,leftcoloumn:lastrow,rightcoloumn).
FYI the message box code is something I don't need Its just their to tell you the Range no.

```
    Sub PivotTableRangeAreas()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

  Dim TopRow1 As Long, TopRow2 As Long, LastRow As Long
  Dim LeftColumn As Long, RightColumn As Long

  TopRow2 = .TableRange2.Row
  With .TableRange1
  TopRow1 = .Row
  LastRow = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1
  LeftColumn = .Column
  RightColumn = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
  End With

  MsgBox "The pivot table named " & .Name & vbCrLf & _
  "occupies these range elements:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
  "With the Report (Page) field: " & vbCrLf & _
  .TableRange2.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & _
  "Without the Report (Page) field: " & vbCrLf & _
  .TableRange1.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
  "First row, with the Report (Page) field: " & TopRow2 & vbCrLf & _
  "First row, without the Report (Page) field: " & TopRow1 & vbCrLf & _
  "Last row: " & LastRow & vbCrLf & _
  "Left column: " & LeftColumn & vbCrLf & _
  "Right column: " & RightColumn, , "Pivot table location."

  End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: If the range is not contiguous - I don't think it might be copied and pasted.

Comment: @peter ya i am unable to copy and paste it. the variable toprow, lastrow, firstcolumn, lastcolumn has helped me to narrow down the range to my preference.
The report generated in pivot table, I am accessing via tablerange1.
I want to select the SEcond column to 6 column in the report area and leave the first 2 rows of that report and last total row of the report. and select copy the entries as string and paste them to my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's just the values that you want to copy? If so, try starting with something like this - it'll put the values into Sheet2 starting at range A1. I'm not sure which range from the pivot table you want to copy to where - you'll have to change some of this to suit:

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim vArray() As Variant

'Copies the values between (Toprow1, LeftColumn) and (LastRow, RightColumn) into an array
vArray = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TopRow1, LeftColumn), Cells(LastRow, RightColumn)).Value
'Pastes the values from the array into Sheet2, starting at A1
Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vArray, 1), UBound(vArray, 2)).Value = vArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error? Do you have a sheet called Sheet2? I can't help more without a bit more information.

Comment: Matt if you please look at my code then I can tell you how i USED YOUR CODE.
I removed the code written between the two END WITH.
Then from your code I copied the code in between the SUB and END SUB.
Then Pasted Your part of the code, Just above my END SUB.
It didnt work this way. Please can you explain How to use this.

Comment: Hi Nishant - what you have done should work. If you look at Sheet2, is any data pasted into there? Is there an error?

Comment: Matt this sheet2 is the Name that we give right ? or the name that is displayed in VBA.

Comment: Hey Matt Sorry About That ya It is working thanks alot man thanks